# Gostaria de saber como construir uma função que conte os valores númericos repetidos em um array?

Tags: javascript

Como contar o valor que mais se repete ?.
Tentei nesse formato e não funciona

```
let array = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,2,3,2,1,3]
let contador = 0
    for(i=0 ;i <= array.length ; i++){
        if(array[i] == array[i + 1]){
            contador += 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você precisa salvar, além de quantas vezes se repete, o número em questão, além disso, dessa forma você só verifica se o próximo número é igual ao anterior, e não se no array tem algum número igual ao que deseja

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro você precisa guardar quantas vezes cada elemento ocorre. Para isso você pode usar um objeto cujas chaves são os números do array, e os respectivos valores são a quantidade de ocorrências.

Depois você tem que encontrar o maior valor entre as ocorrências.

E por fim, você percorre os elementos do objeto e só imprime aqueles cuja quantidade de ocorrências é igual ao maior valor (afinal, pode ter empate, então eu fiz de um jeito que mostre todos os mais frequentes):

```js
// os números 2 e 3 ocorrem 4 vezes cada (ambos sáo os mais frequentes)
let array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 100, 8];

// contar quantas vezes cada elemento ocorre e guardar em "cont"
let cont = {};
for (const n of array) {
    // se o número já tinha uma contagem, atualiza somando 1
    if (cont.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
        cont[n] += 1;
    } else cont[n] = 1; // senão, inicia a contagem do número com 1
}

// encontrar a maior ocorrência
let max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(cont));

// encontrar todos os valores que ocorrem "max" vezes
console.log(`Elementos mais frequentes, ocorrem ${max} vezes:`);
for (const n of Object.keys(cont)) {
    if (cont[n] == max) console.log(n);
}
```

Primeiro eu criei o objeto `cont`, que no exemplo acima, depois do primeiro `for`, ficará assim:

```
{ '1': 2, '2': 4, '3': 4, '4': 1, '5': 2, '6': 1, '7': 1, '8': 2, '9': 1, '100': 1 }
```

Ou seja, as chaves são os números do array, e os valores são a quantidade de vezes que cada um ocorre.

Depois eu uso [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) para encontrar o maior valor entre as ocorrências (usando [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) para obter somente os valores de `cont`). Mas como `Object.values` retorna um array e `Math.max` recebe vários argumentos (e não um array de valores), eu uso [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) para que os elementos do array retornado por `Object.values` sejam passados como argumentos para `Math.max`.

Tendo a maior quantidade de ocorrências, eu percorro `cont` e só imprimo os números que ocorreram esta quantidade de vezes (já que pode ter mais de um).

Answer (score 0):

```
dados = ['1', '2', '3', '3', '1']
var contabiliza_dados = { };

for (var i = 0, j = quantidade_itens; i < j; i++) {
   contabiliza_dados[dados[i]] = (contabiliza_dados[dados[i]] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(contabiliza_dados);
```